# how to detect tap on a 2d animation on unity3d

Tags: ios, click, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have a 2d animation on scene.When I try to detect tap or click on the animation using OnMouseDown function it doesn't work.But it works using the following code

```
Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)
```

it works but it detects tap on whole window and if I print the onject name like

```
Debug.log(this.name);
```

it prints the name of the animated sprite name.I want to detect tap only on the animated sprite.Please anyone help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **Raycasting** to detect that. Cast a 2D ray down from the input location and check if it hits something. [Here's good info about it](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html).

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    var hit : RaycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

    if(hit != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("object clicked: "+hit.collider.tag);
    }
}
```